# How can i combine text widget over the image

Tags: flutter, dart

here is some of my process

1- i am picking image from galley using `image_picker`

2- i display it using `Image.file` widget

3- i wrap `Image.file` into `stack widget` and put Text at center like following

```
                    Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.file(
                        File(myImage),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      const Text('Hello world')
                    ],
                  ),
```

4- then uploading image to server using `firebase_storage`

now the question

How can i upload my image with my `Text('Hello world')`
in other world : How do I make text as part of an image

any plugins for that ?

What should I look for?

Comment: U can make an object with filename and the text you wish, then make a json to upload it to server

Answer (score 3):

You can use [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package, and take a screen shot of stack widget and send you `screenshot image` to your server. like this:

```
ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.file(
                        File(myImage),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      const Text('Hello world')
                    ],
                  ),
),
```

and you can get the image like this:

```
screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) {
    //Capture Done
    setState(() {
        _imageFile = image;
    });
}).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
});
```

here `_imageFile` is `Uint8List` , and you can send _imageFile to your server.

Comment: thanks @eamirho3ein for this awesome answer .. 
i have two question for that .. does it effect of the original image quality ? ..
does firebase storage accept Uint8List ?

Comment: @MohammedHamdan yes it will affect the image quality but it I think it i the only way you have.

Comment: does firebase storage accept Uint8List ?

Comment: @MohammedHamdan I don't know that, but if not, you can convert it to the accepted one.